# How to fill custom area in mapbox?

Tags: mapbox

I have following map in mapbox editor:
[image]

Is it possible to fill custom area of the map ? (in this example, area is selected, I can see its attributes)
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to [filter the data](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/selectors/) and then [polygon styles](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/styling-polygons/) to style the layer.

For instance, if the ID you can rely on is `ID_0`, then

```
#GEO_adm2[ID_0 = 81] {
  polygon-fill:#f00;
}
```